# Alembic: Can't use literal_binds setting without as_sql mode

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm using alembic to generate revisions using sqlalchemy.

When running the command:

```
alembic revision --autogenerate
```

I get:

> ERROR [alembic.util.messaging] Can't use literal_binds setting without as_sql mode
>   FAILED: Can't use literal_binds setting without as_sql mode

Aside from the metadata and database_uri, I'm using alembic's default configuration. I have used it to generate revisions in the past, without encountering this error.

I haven't been able to find any clear information on this error (closest I got was [an issue with literal bind and autogenerate](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/issues/219)). I know which file triggers the error ([github link](https://github.com/sugarguo/Flask_Blog/blob/master/ext_lib/alembic/ddl/impl.py)), but I don't know why the `as_sql` parameter is set to `False`, or why `literal_binds` is set to `True`.

Any hint or lead would be very appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve it anyway?